# Mkusb (or my stupidity) trashed my usb

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

While `mkusb` was working to make a persistent Ubuntu Live USB, for a friend who damaged his HDD, I pulled out the USB cause it was taking too long. After that, I plugged it back in and I couldn't format it and when I select the option to format, it showed:

```
Error creating partition on /dev/sda: Command-line parted --align optimal --script "/dev/sda" "mkpart primary ext2 1MiB 15472047103b"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: The location 1MiB is outside of the device /dev/sda.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I tried almost every guide but I don't get any results and `fdisk` seems to have completely forgotten that I have an 8 GB stick and shows 1.4 GB.

Comment: Flash drive is in hybrid format. See this to clear it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

Comment: Use mkusb to wipe the first megabyte and try again.